# My HTML form has its action linked to php code. When the submit button is clicked though, the form redirects to the PHP file. How can I prevent this?

Tags: php, html

I have a signup form in my HTML file. The action of the form is a PHP file. I want the PHP to process the entered data and leave the user on the signup page (HTML.) However, when the submit button is clicked, the website redirects to the PHP file. Is there some way of preventing this?

I have tried setting the form's target to "_self", but that didn't help.

```
HTML:
<? include('signup.php'); ?>
<?php include('errors.php'); ?>
<form method="post" action="signup.php">
***More Input fields here***
<button type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: You might want to learn more about how [the action attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) works. That said, you are probably looking for ajax.

Answer (score 1):

you can actually leave that empty, so the same page gets targeted :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove or blank the action attribute in form like as:

**HTML:**

```
    <?php include('signup.php'); 
     include('errors.php'); 
     ?>

    <form method="post">
    ***More Input fields here***
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to refresh the page and handle user input you can use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Simple example:

```html
<form>
    <label for="username">
        Username
        <input type="text" id="username">
    </label>
    <label for="password">
        Password
        <input type="password" id="password">
    </label>
    <button id="submit"></button>
</form>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'signup.php',
                data:
                    {
                        name: $('#username').val(),
                        password: $('#password').val()
                    }
            }).done(function (msg) {
                alert('Data Saved: ' + msg);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you want to send POST request to the same page, just remove `action` attribute from the form

```html
<form method="post">
***More Input fields here***
<button type="submit" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it with ajax: the page does not get redirected.